# How to create circle button with image background and CLICKING feel IN Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

Right now i can change the look of the button to an ellipse with a background image. 
However, when i click on it, i don't feel the CLICKING EFFECT of the normal buttons in Silverlight
Can anyone help me how to get that effect?

this is my XAML style for the round button

```
<style x:Key="roundButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Properties="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                 <Ellipse width="100" height="100">
                     <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="./icon.png">
                     </Ellipse.Fill>
                 </Ellipse>

              </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</style>
```

after searching around i know that i should use the VisualStateManager in Systems.Window. This is how my XAML looks now but i still can't get the CLICKING feeling like normal buttons

```
<Style x:Key="roundButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="./icon.png" />
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>

                    <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                        <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                        </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                    </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the triggers for your button for the respective state.

```
<style x:Key="roundButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Properties="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                 <Ellipse width="100" height="100">
                     <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="./icon.png"/>
                     </Ellipse.Fill>
                 </Ellipse>

                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                       <!-- mouse over look and feel here -->
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                       <!-- clicked look and feel here -->
                    </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
              </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi,I am sorry for not mentioning that i want to do this in Silverlight not WPF. The ControlTemplate.Triggers won't be found. what should i do in order to let it be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin=".2,.2">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.2" Color="White" />
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Blue" />

                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Far more simple way is to use Blend. Drag and Drop Ellipse, convert it into control(button). Go to StatesTab adjust the states accordingly. Normally, on pressed state, apply scale trasform to reduce the button size and use translate transform to move the button (appro 2px amount) towards bottom/right would do the trick.

HTH

Comment: i used blend to convert the ellipse shape into button. However, when i click on state tab i don't see any setting available for it. Can you guide me how to set it up in order to get that Clicking Feeling one? thank you

Comment: http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/creating_custom_button_pg1.htm
This could help you :)